# top not dumping correct cpu usage

Tags: linux, bash

I have a program that parses file dumps generated by dumping top into a text file. For example, I use `top -n 1 -b > dump1`. The problem is when my system is under load for example 60% cpu utilization top always returns 3-4% usage of cpu. When I run top manually, the cpu starts at 3-4% usage, then after 1-2 seconds it will jump to the expected load. The question is how do I capture top a couple of seconds after it has been executed?

Comment: not the solution but try two iteration with delay `top -n 2 b -d 10`

Comment: you know that `-n` option will top iteration.So why not increase it?

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try bash script which only capture cpu usage and put in log file like

```
#!/bin/bash


while :; do
    top -bn 1 | sed -n '3p' >> log.txt
    sleep 2
done
```

Here `top` command fire every 2 seconds.